# PCAP Go using Raw Sockets Checksum Calculation

Tags: sockets, tcp, go, ip, raw-ethernet

I'm writing a frame/datagram/packet manipulation program which forwards frames from one source to another. I'm using the Go layers library to manipulate the frames.

If I do not set the option to calculate checksums the SYN packet get's to the computer running this go code and it gets forwarded. However, I've changed the packet dstIP, srcIP while the checksum remains the same, the reciever never sends back a SYN ACK, I suspect this is because the checksum is now in error due to the change.

But, the layers library includes an option called CalculateChecksum, which if I turn it on to be true the computer running this program gets the frame, but never transmits it to the receiver.

This is my first time with RAW sockets, so I'm working on theories and no experience, any ideas?

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/gopacket"
    "code.google.com/p/gopacket/layers"
    "code.google.com/p/gopacket/pcap"
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {

    if handle, err := pcap.OpenLive("enp3s0", 1600, true, 100); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        packetSource := gopacket.NewPacketSource(handle, handle.LinkType())
        for packet := range packetSource.Packets() {

            if ethLayer := packet.Layer(layers.LayerTypeEthernet); ethLayer != nil {

                eth, _ := ethLayer.(*layers.Ethernet)
                //eth.DstMAC, _ = net.ParseMAC("14:10:9f:d1:47:e5")

                eth.SrcMAC, _ = net.ParseMAC("98:90:96:a3:93:e0")

                if ipLayer := packet.Layer(layers.LayerTypeIPv4); ipLayer != nil {

                    ip, _ := ipLayer.(*layers.IPv4)
                    if ip.SrcIP.Equal(net.ParseIP("192.168.1.72")) {
                        fmt.Println("from cal")
                        //change the dst IP to something 192.168.1.65
                        eth.DstMAC, _ = net.ParseMAC("00:90:F5:D6:02:FD")
                        ip.SrcIP = net.IP{192, 168, 1, 70}
                        ip.DstIP = net.IP{192, 168, 1, 73}

                    }
                    if ip.SrcIP.Equal(net.ParseIP("192.168.1.73")) {
                        fmt.Println("from me")
                        //change the dst IP to something 192.168.1.65
                        eth.DstMAC, _ = net.ParseMAC("AC:16:2D:49:69:4B")
                        ip.SrcIP = net.IP{192, 168, 1, 70}
                        ip.DstIP = net.IP{192, 168, 1, 72}

                    }

                    if tcpLayer := packet.Layer(layers.LayerTypeTCP); tcpLayer != nil {

                        tcp, _ := tcpLayer.(*layers.TCP)

                        buf := gopacket.NewSerializeBuffer()
                        opts := gopacket.SerializeOptions{}
                        opts.FixLengths = true
                        /* I WISH TO RE-COMPUTE CHECKSUMS HOWEVER WHEN THIS OPTION IS TRUE
                           I NEVER TRANSMIT THE FRAME*/
                        opts.ComputeChecksums = true
                        gopacket.SerializeLayers(buf, opts,
                            eth,
                            ip,
                            tcp,
                            gopacket.Payload([]byte(tcp.LayerPayload())))
                        packetData := buf.Bytes()

                        handle.WritePacketData(buf)

                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should start by assigning the return value of `SerializeLayers` and checking for an error